# How to read in and assign values from a txt file?

Tags: import, data, variable

I have a text file that I would like to import into *Mathematica* - after searching around the internet, I can't seem to find any pages that explain how to do this:

The text file containes these four lines:

```
10
1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8
1000 100
```

In my Mathematica code, I want to assign:

```
a = 10
list1 = {1, 2, 3}
list2 = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
b = 1000
c = 100
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm not very versed in *Mathematica* so any help will be appreciated, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? This is very basic. A quick exploration of the documentation would teach you a lot and should easily get you up to speed. Look up `Import` for CSV files, and then look at the list manipulation documentation pages.

Comment: @user6014 See my answer, I don't think complicated hierarchical left-hand-sides in assignments are something that everybody knows.

Comment: @roman There's more than one way to skin a cat, though.

Answer (score 5):

```
{{a}, list1, list2, {b, c}} = Import[filename, "Table"]
(*    {{10}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1000, 100}}    *)
```

Notice how the left-hand side mimics the structure of the right-hand side, which you can see in the output line: a nested list of lists representing the numbers on the different lines in the file.